# Transfer inline style to external style sheet

Tags: css, inline

I have used inline styling to put a radiused border around the five images in my index file. How do I apply this style to them by declaring css attributes/values in the external style sheet. Here is a demo of the index file  http://jsfiddle.net/23nfM/embedded/result/

```
    !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>pedrosdigitalsolutions.com</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link type="image/x-icon" href="/custom pds/images/cheat_1.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
      <link media="screen" type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php include 'header.php' ?>
      <div id="content">

           <p class="tab"><font size="7"><b>For all things</b></font><br>
            <font size="7"><b>Electronic Arduino</b></font><br>
            <font size="7"><b>and "other stuff"</b></font><br>
            <font size="6"><b>Love ♥ The Duino</b></font>
         </p>
         <img style="position:absolute; top:515px; left:692px; width:300px; height:225px; border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 8px" 
            src="http://www.pedroduino.com/custom pd/images/Manual Shift Register 300x225.gif">

         <img style="position:absolute; top:215px; left:692px; width:300px; height:225px; border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 8px" 
           src="http://www.pedroduino.com/custom pd/images/Manual LCD 300x225.gif">

         <img style="position:absolute; top:515px; left:150px; width:300px; height:225px; border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 8px" 
            src="http://www.pedroduino.com/custom pd/images/LCDBitmap_via_SR.gif">

         <img style="position:absolute; top:815px; left:150px; width:300px; height:225px; border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 8px" 
            src="http://www.pedroduino.com/custom pd/images/8_LED_Array.gif">

        <img style="position:absolute; top:815px; left:692px; width:300px; height:225px; border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 8px" 
            src="http://www.pedroduino.com/custom pd/images/Nicks Clock 300x225.gif">    

       </div>
     <?php include 'footer.php' ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="nagging-menu.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </body>
</html>



    body {
    background: #efefef;
    border: none;
    color: #3F4C6B;
    font: normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; }


#content {
    height: 950px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 950px;

     }


.default {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%; }


.fixed {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5px;
    width: 100%; }


#footer {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #98B0D9;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#98B0D9);

     height: 70px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
}


h1 { line-height: 15px; }


#header {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#606C88, #3F4C6B) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#606C88, #3F4C6B);
    border-color: #0F1620 #000000;
    border-image: none;

    height: 93px;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto; }


#logo {
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0; }


#menu {
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c3d9ff, #98b0d9);
        background: linear-gradient(#c3d9ff, #98b0d9) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 5px;
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 135px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 5;
        float: center;
         }


#navi {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 0; }


ul { padding: 0; }

    ul li {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-right: 15px; }

        ul li a {
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition-property: color, background;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 3px 7px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; }

            ul li a:hover {
                -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
                -webkit-transition-property: color, background;
                background: #606C88;
                color: #ff0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip out the inline styles, and put something like this in your external style sheet:

```
#content img {position:absolute; width:300px; height:225px; border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 8px}
```

Some styles specific to each image have been left out. For those, add a class or id to the image and then write styles for that image. E.g. the first image could have a class of `.lalala` and then you'd do this in your style sheet:

```
.lalala {top:515px; left:692px;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralph. I saw that the images were inheriting their style from the content div but was at a loss as to how to apply the style to only the images.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that, but the easiest path for your current code would be to declare the border and some other styles in the stylesheet, and then position the images with inline styles.

So in the stylesheet, add:

`#content img {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:225px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 8px;
}`

Then in the html, remove all of the inline styles on each image except `top` and `left`.

Comment: Thanks for that Drew it's good to have two different methods of resolving a problem.